# Tor comunicating to other IPs beside my guard node, should it happen?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, relays, guard-node, ip-address-leak, tor-network

Running netstat and analyzing my established connections I noticed sometimes tor talks to other IPs that aren't my guard node. I'm not sure if this is supposed to happen because I very very new to this. At first I thought this could be my tor choosing it's relays but not sure if this' how it works. I want to know if this is expected.
I searched for info about this IPs. Some of them are labeled as "tor related" or are exit nodes, others are not. I remember most of them being from Germany, which leads me to another question.

Why are there so many German relays? Sometimes all my three relays happen to be from Germany. I heard about end-to-end attacks but don't know if this is the case.

Im not posting the ips. My browser's GPG were verified.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is normal. Tor doesn't have a single guard, but instead maintains a *guard set* of several guards. You can find these listed in tor's `state` file. A tor client may also connect to other relays in order to test their eligibility for being added to this guard set.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK for *any* self-reorganizing network, including the Tor one! The red flag - in means of connection listing - if there will be a connections to the IP addresses you're sure that are not members of Tor network and not a services you do need to use.